# Issue on DXF code for an ELLIPSE for AutoCad

Tags: autocad, ellipse, dxf

I´m having an issue with a DXF code for an Ellipse, I´m trying to have it Graphed by AutoCad 2019 but it won´t recognize the code for an unknown reason. I would greatly apreciate any insight on the issue. Thanks a lot in advance

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
ELLIPSE
8
0
10
43.6886
20
16.2019
30
0
11
64.4949
21
16.2019
31
0
210
0
220
0
230
0
40
0.4
41
0
42
6.28319
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

Comment: ELLIPSE is an entity beyond DXF R12, all sections are required, also subclass markers and handles are mandatory. DXF R2000+ (I ignore R13/14) need much more work, look here for minimal requirements: https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/dxfinternals/filestructure.html#minimal-dxf-content

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing some AutoCAD 'housekeeping' stuff in your dxf file.  You have all the geometry bits for your ellipse, but AutoCAD doesn't know where to put them in the overall DXF file.  So you have to include things like the drawing 'Handle' and the other required elements that place the ellipse in the overall framework of the whole drawing.  An ellipse in a DXF file starts out like what is shown below:

```
ENTITIES
  0
ELLIPSE
  5
86
330
70
100
AcDbEntity
  8
 0
100
AcDbEllipse
 10
43.6886
 20
16.2019
 30
0
```

The R2000 dxf spec will tell you what all those pieces are for specifically, but everything above

```
AcDbEllipse
 10
```

is needed to place the ellipse in the greater context of the rest of the drawing.  Without it, the ellipse would not be recognized.

I can tell you that code `8` identifies the layer the entity is on, in this case, `0` and code `5` identifies a unique handle (id code) for the entity, in this case `86`.  The handle must be unique for every entity in a dxf file.  If you are manipulating/creating dxf entities in code, you have to be very careful to never have duplicate handles.

Answer (score 0):

This ia an example of DXF with a line from 100,100,0 to 200,200,0

```
999
Start Section ***************************************************************
  0
SECTION
    999
Start Entities ****************************************************************
  2
ENTITIES
    999
Line ************************************************************************
  0
LINE
  8
LAYER1
  10
100
  20
100
  30
0
  11
200
  21
200
  31
0
  0
ENDSEC
    999
End Section ***************************************************************
    999
End File ********************************************************************
  0
EOF
```

999 is for comment
then you have to start section and entities 
at the end close section and file
If you need more Info contact me